# Getting Warning: "ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations." in ElasticNetCV sklear

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, data-science

I am trying to run elasticnet regression on a particular dataset. This is my code:

```
elastic= ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio = [0.001,0.005,0.01,0.03,0.07,0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1],
                          alphas = [0.0001, 0.0003, 0.0006, 0.001, 0.003, 0.006, 
                                    0.01, 0.03, 0.06, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1, 3, 6], 
                          max_iter = 50000, cv = 10,tol=0.001)
elastic.fit(x_train,y_train)
alpha=elastic.alpha_
ratio=elastic.alpha_
print('best alpha:',alpha)
print('best l1 ratio:',ratio)
```

I am receiving the following warning and unable to finish execution properly.

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:527: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 1.1304511543456042, tolerance: 0.16652297337822466
  tol, rng, random, positive)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:527: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 1.3276808651494596, tolerance: 0.17237036604178843
  tol, rng, random, positive)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:527: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 1.1082449562463794, tolerance: 0.17237036604178843
  tol, rng, random, positive)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:527: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 1.1717336811567476, tolerance: 0.16652297337822466
  tol, rng, random, positive)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:527: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 1.147435308235048, tolerance: 0.17237036604178843
  tol, rng, random, positive)
```

I have tried increasing tolerance value. However, the problem does not seem to change